# How to separate different parts of an iPhone views?

Tags: iphone, view, uiviewcontroller, nib

I have a common header and common footer in all the view controllers of an iPhone application.
What I want to do is, I want to separate the header and footer into different nib, .h and .m files and want to integrate these into one view.

How to do that?

Thanks all.
Guru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 UIViewController(s):

- HeaderViewController.m (with .h and .xib)
- FooterViewController.m (with .h and .xib)

Then in you view you add them by code: (Or via Interface Builder if you want)

```
HeaderViewController *header = [[HeaderViewController alloc] init];
[header setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 100)]; // For example
[self.view addSubview:header.view];
```

In IB: Add a new UIViewController in IB, change the classe UIVIewController by HeaderViewController, link it with an `IBOutlet` (header), then you just have to do `[self.view addSubview:header.view];`.

[image]